# How to solve multiple thread static variable incrementation?

Tags: java, multithreading, increment, volatile

So my problem essentially is,that even though I use static volatile int variable for incrementation some of my data doesn't remain unique which would be my goal(I number my elements).

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private String str;
    private Fifo f;
    private int i;
    private static volatile int n=0;
    public Producer(String str,int i,Fifo f) ....
    
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.go();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            ;
        }
    }
    
    void go() throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(i);
                int l=n++;
                String k=str+" "+l+" ";
                f.put(k);
            System.out.println("produced "+str+" "+l+" "+System.currentTimeMillis()%100000);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is in the function go(). I number my elements, I have multiple Producer objects running as independent threads, but sometimes they act like they have no clue whether n has been updated or not so I get same indexes.
Any ideas?
(I get what could be the problem, but I have no clue how to solve it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding as to what `volatile` does. The keyword `volatile` introduces happens-before semantics between writes and reads. It does not, however, make multiple operations atomic.

If we were to write the semantics of `n++` "by hand" (please never do this, it is for explanatory purposes only), it would look something like that:

```
final int result;
n = (result = n) + 1;
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WOskMY)

Looking at this code, we see that we have to:

1. read the value of `n`,
2. store it in some temporary variable `result`,
3. increment it by `1`, and
4. write the (incremented) value back to `n`

So we have multiple operations. If those operations are executed in parallel multiple times by different threads, then we can see a manifold of possible interweavings that lead to inconsistent data. For example, two threads could both read the (current) value of `n`. Both would increment the value by one and both would write the new value back to `n`. This means that two threads have executed the "increment", but the value of `n` has only incremented by `1` instead of `2`.

We can use specialized classes - in this case [`AtomicInteger`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/panama/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) - to avoid this problem. The usage looks something like this:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    ...

    private static final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);

    ...

    void go() throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
                ...
                int l = n.getAndIncrement();
                ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could this be an another solution?  synchronized static int increment() {
  return n++;
 }

Comment: Yes, this would also work since static methods synchronize on the `class`-object. I would, however, recommend using the `AtomicInteger` implementation.

Comment: @Makkador Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: it seems to me that no matter how many times we would post these answers, a "once a week question on the volatile + atomic" is a stackoverflow thing already.

Comment: To be fair @Eugene, I am studying CS and just encountered the same problem for a project on Multithreading. How was I supposed to know that? Read documentation on classes I dont even know exist?

Comment: @ThanasisNamikazee thats totally OK, I get it. This ain't easy and it's not suppoed to be.