# Different results using ConcurrentHashMap with multiple Threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, concurrenthashmap

I am splitting the String List in main into 2 different Threads to map the words inside.
Every time I execute this code I get different mapping results.
Either I have a BIG logic flaw, or there is something I am missing about Threads and Concurrent Collections.
 Can anyone understand why is this happening?
There are 8 "a" 's and 6 "b" 's added to the list.
P.S. this does not happen If I use ONE Thread only!

EDIT 1 
changing map.put() to map.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum), Still doesnt work

EDIT 2
following solution I didnt use if/else, only merge and it works as expected.

```
 public class MyThread extends Thread {
     private List<String> list;
     private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map;


    public MyThread(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map, List<String> list) {
        this.map = map;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (String word : list){
           map.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
       }
   }

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> getMap() {
       return map;
   }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("a");list.add("a");list.add("a");list.add("a");list.add("b");list.add("b");list.add("b");
    list.add("a");list.add("a");list.add("a");list.add("a");list.add("b");list.add("b");list.add("b");

    MyThread[] ts = new MyThread[2];
    int start = 0;
    int end = list.size()/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        ts[i] = new MyThread(map,new ArrayList<>(list.subList(start, end)));
        ts[i].start();

        start = end;
        end = list.size();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        ts[i].join();
    }

    for(String word : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println("Key = " + word + ". Value = " + map.get(word));
    }
}
```

Comment: "*`map.put(word, map.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);`*" - These operations are not executed atomically. I would advice to use a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>` instead. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69780928/how-to-solve-multiple-thread-static-variable-incrementation) by [Makkador](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15534526/makkador) has a similar root cause, although it is not a duplicate I think.

Comment: Or do `map.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);`

Comment: @Turing85 using ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> and updating the map with put(StringKey, incremented AtomicInteger or 1) still returns varying results

Comment: The idea is to not use `put(....)` to override existing values, but modify existing values by `get(...)`tin an `AtomicInteger` from the `ConcurrentHashMap` and calling `incrementAndGet()` on it. But honestly: seeing @shmosel's comment, this seems a lot cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: @Turing85, ok mind is blown. Did not actually think of that. Will keep you posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing - you should use `map.containsKey(word)` instead `map.contains(word)`.

About different results after some runnings. There is no atomically code when you invoke `containsKey()` and `merge()` methods. Both of them atomically separately, but are not atomically together.
The solution is just to change your code and call only `merge()` which is atomic. You don't need `if-else` section at all.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (String word : list) {
            map.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
```